# linux: times or clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC) ? which one is faster?

Tags: c, linux, kernel

I've tested times() and clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC) on several machines, and the results is confused (run each api 10M times with single thread):

Thinkpad P50 Xeon E3-1505Mv5 [Skylake 14nm]:

```
times(NULL)                   : 450ms
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC): 325ms
```

You can see on Skylake clock_gettime is faster than times.

Here is the result on a Xeon E5-2430 [Sandy Bridge 32nm]:

```
times(NULL)                   : 600ms
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC): 1420ms
```

times(NULL) is faster now.

I also doing the same test on an old Thinkpad W510 I7-720QM [Clarksfield 45nm]:

```
times(NULL)                   : 1.73s
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC): 20.4s
```

Seems like there a some new featrues implemented by newer hardware, which boosted the clock_gettime performance?

Comment: If your point is to measure performance by getting a clock many times, I suggest you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34810392/assembler-instruction-rdtsc and also about `rdtscp`.

Comment: No, I don't use this code to measure performance. I use it to timing some timers, but it could be launched very frequently. So the effectiveness of the API itself is very important. BTW: windows GetTickCount64 API is very quick, only take 60ms on the same P50 machine. Why linux slower than windows for this function?

Comment: For example: to determine if we need to send the next heartbeat package, or examing is a user session stay valid, etc. there are many "monotonic time" intensive usages.

Comment: Why not use an actual timer provided by the OS then?  On Linux, `timer_settime()` or `timerfd_settime()`....

Comment: Because many tasks need timing is fundamentally not a periodically task. Or using timer under some cases will resulting more performance degradation. For example: determine if a user session within a incoming http request is expired, and many more other cases.

Comment: The answer to the stated question does not matter. `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts)` is fast enough to never be a bottleneck in sane use. If you find you are using it too often, use a signal handler or dedicated thread to update a lockless/atomic time variable, and have the users examine that. (You might suffer a bit from cacheline ping-pong in multithreaded processes; there are many ways to mitigate that. You'll also need to use atomic built-ins, but all the major POSIXy C compilers do provide them, so it turns out not to be any issue for portability, either.)

Comment: We are already using a dedicated timing thread many years under some case. And of course with atomic (we have our own assemble atomic implementation, we also use the vc intrinsic, gcc built-in, windows atomic api, linux api etc. some times). But sometimes timing thread is not suitable, For Example: 1. atomic has its own cost (cache invalid, unavoidable memory barrier on some arch like x86 ...); 2. not suitable for using thread in some cases; 3. need accurately timing, and etc. I don't want talk about how to workaround with it, Just want to know what the  result means & why it's slower then msw

Answer (score 1):

Don't [`times(2)`)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) and [`clock_gettime(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) measure different things? `times()` measure CPU used running your process whereas `clock_gettime()` measures wall clock time regardless of whether your process is "on-CPU" or not.

If the clock used by `clock_gettime()` is supported by the vDSO version then I would have thought the **overhead** of calling it would typically be comparable to `times()` but obviously they could return different results depending on whether your process was descheduled at some point.